# Browser navigation broken by use of React Error Boundaries

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

When an error is thrown in our React 16 codebase, it is caught by our top-level error boundary. The `ErrorBoundary` component happily renders an error page when this happens.

Where the ErrorBoundary sits

```
   return (
     <Provider store={configureStore()}>
       <ErrorBoundary>
         <Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
       </ErrorBoundary>
     </Provider>
   )
```

However, when navigating back using the browser back button (one click), the URL changes in the address but the page does not update.

I have tried shifting the error boundary down the component tree but this issue persists.

Any clues on where this issue lies?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The op has probably found a resolution by now, but for the benefit of anyone else having this issue I'll explain why I think its happening and what can be done to resolve it.

This is probably occurring due to the conditional rendering in the ErrorBoundary rendering the error message even though the history has changed.

Although not shown above, the render method in the ErrorBoundary is probably similar to this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.hasError) {
    return <h1>An error has occurred.</h1>
  }

  return this.props.children;
}
```

Where hasError is being set in the `componentDidCatch` lifecycle method.

Once the state in the ErrorBoundary has been set it will always render the error message until the state changes (hasError to false in the example above). The child components (the Router component in this case) will not be rendered, even when the history changes.

To resolve this, make use of the react-router [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher order component, by wrapping the export of the ErrorBoundary to give it access to the history via the props:

```
export default withRouter(ErrorBoundary);
```

In the ErrorBoundary constructor retrieve the history from the props and setup a handler to listen for changes to the current location using [history.listen](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#listening). When the location changes (back button clicked etc.) if the component is in an error state, it is cleared enabling the children to be rendered again.

```
const { history } = this.props;

history.listen((location, action) => {
  if (this.state.hasError) {
    this.setState({
      hasError: false,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: glad it helped you both!

Comment: +1. I also had to add this to not update the erred out child component on setState and throw the error again thereby set error again in the state.

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (!this.state.error || nextState.error);
}

Comment: absolutely fantastic

Comment: react-router v6 removed this hoc x.x

Answer (score 11):

To add to jdavies' answer above, make sure you register the history listener in a `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` (using `[]` to denote it has no dependencies), and **unregister** it in a `componentWillUnmount` or `useEffect` return statement, otherwise you may run into issues with `setState` getting called in an unmounted component.

Example:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        this.setState({ hasError: false });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The analog to jdavies answer for React Router 6 is:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation()
const originalPathname = useRef(pathname)

useEffect(() => {
  if (pathname !== originalPathname.current) {
    resetErrorBoundary()
  }
}, [pathname, resetErrorBoundary])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in React 18

Answer (score 1):

jdavies comment is the way to go,

but, if you are confused by this, basically you make it look like this:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { history } = props;
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      if (this.state["hasError"]) {
        this.setState({
          hasError: false,
        });
      }
    });
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

       ...
```

then at the end of the file you add:

```
export default withRouter(ErrorBoundary);
```

(don't forget to `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";` at top)

also, if you were using e.g. `export class ErrorBoundry ...` like i was, don't forget to change the `import { ErrorBoundary } from "./ErrorBoundry";` to `import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundry";` wherever you use it e.g. App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using `ErrorBoundary` with `FallbackComponent` at the top level of the tree, to catch all errors, display the error page and report the problem using a dedicated endpoint on the backend.

In order to refresh the page after `history.push(...)`, instead of checking/modifying the state, I'm just listening for history change and calling `resetErrorBoundary` function as described in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary#errorboundary-with-fallbackcomponent-prop

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorComponent} onError={...}>
      ...
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

```
const ErrorComponent = ({ error, resetErrorBoundary }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  history.listen(() => {
    if (typeof resetErrorBoundary === 'function') {
      resetErrorBoundary();
    }
  });
  
  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default ErrorComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

***tl;dr*** wrap components where you expect errors with error boundaries but not the entire tree

Tried first @jdavies answer using `withRouter` but then found a better solution for my use case: [Dan from the React-Team advised against using HOCs with Error Boundaries and rather use them at stragetic places](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/890716011133100032?lang=en).

In that Twitter thread is a debate around the pros and cons though and Dan left it open which way you should go but I found his thoughts convincing.

So what I did was to just wrap those *strategic places* where I expect an error and not the entire tree. I prefer this for my use case because I can throw more expressive, specific error pages than before (*something went wrong* vs *there was an auth error*).

Comment: Can you expand on the alternative to using an HoC to solve the question that was originally asked? Thanks.